# holomorphic differentials on hyperelliptic Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

I'm a bit lost with the general form of holomorphic one forms on the compact hyperelliptic Riemann surface $M$ defined by $w^2=h(z)$ where $h$ can have an even or odd number of distinct, simple zeroes.

I need to find that $\frac{dz}{w}$ is holomorphic if the genus $g$ of $M$ is at least $1$ and as a follow up that for all polynomials $p(z)$ with $deg(p)<g, p(z)\frac{dz}{w}$ is a holomorphic differential as well.

For the first part I just considered where $\frac{dz}{w}$ could have poles, which would be the branch points. But locally, $w$ goes as $\sqrt z$ so this does seem to indicate a pole to me, or can I not use a kind of two-sheet model for this? I see people saying that this is a trivial fact so maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

Any hints would be appreciated, if at all possible I would still try to find it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $dz=h’(z)^{-1}d(h(z))=2wdw/h’(z)$. So if $h$ has no double zero, $dz/w$ does extend to a holomorphic differential even around the points where $w$ vanishes.

Comment: Is it then true that $p(z)\frac{dz}{w} = p(h^{-1}(z))\frac{2wdw}{h'(z)}$?

Comment: Not exactly... $p(z)dz/w=p(z)wdw/(wh’(z))=2p(z)/h’(z) \cdot dw$ is also holomorphic near $\{w=0\}$.

Comment: Alright I got it! If the degree is greater than $g$, you get that the degree of $p(z)/h'(z)$ is at least 1 which always has a pole at infinity, is that correct? It seems I'm really struggling with these parts of Riemann surfaces...

Comment: Oh right, there’s something about infinity too, I didn’t even think of it. I didn’t like these parts too much either... but I suppose it’s something like that that is supposed to happen.